# CRT-Screen-Compact-Desktop-Calculators of the 60's, could versions of this tech have been made as word-processors or even video-games?

Tags: calculator, delay-lines

CRT-Screen-Compact-Desktop-Calculators of the 60's, could versions of this tech have been made as word-processors or even video-games?

Word-Processors - How difficult would it have been to save what was on the delay-line memory onto tape.  ( A simple cable could have connected to printers, or simply take tapes to compatible printers )

Video-Games - This would probably involve more circuitry / logic, and of course very few could have afforded one for video games.

NOTE - I cannot find how data on Delay-line memory was edited after input, assuming some machines allowed editing, these crt-calculators would probably not have.

A reason for asking is to possibly discover unknown machines. And am now thinking if Delay-line memory may have been an explanation for some very early radar consoles appearing to generate alpha-numeric characters on their screen ( not done by a transparent physical overlay on their screen ), which I have seen on tv, which seemingly appeared to be from the late 40's.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delay-line_memory#Magnetostrictive_delay_lines) says one implemention _was_ used for video terminals - tiny ones - 4 lines x 40 char/line - so you _could_ have composed a tweet on one.  But networks hadn't been invented ... so only _you_ could read it.

Comment: It might help if you add _why/for what purpose_ this is asked.

Comment: A reason for asking is to possibly discover unknown machines. And am now thinking if Delay-line memory may have been an explanation for some very early radar consoles appearing to generate alpha-numeric characters on their screen ( not done by a transparent physical overlay on their screen ), which I have seen on tv, which seemingly appeared to be from the late 40's.

Comment: @infomtn No, those displays were based on special to type vector displays using serious machines to be driven, not calculators. Machines with drum and core.

Comment: What do mean by 'editing delay line memory'?  It was a form of storage where each bit had to be periodically rewritten, much as dynamic RAM requires refresh.  To change it, you write the new value of the bit.  The sequential access means you have to wait for the sequence of bits you want, much as on rotating memories (disk/drum) but does not intrinsically change your ability to update those bits.

Comment: @Raffzahn , You typed "those displays were based on special to type vector displays", any links or info to those " special to type vector displays" would be useful

Comment: You mean [like this](http://www.tc.faa.gov/its/worldpac/techrpt/rd73-149.pdf)?  Though that's 1974, not early radar.

Comment: I'm a little confused as to how the OP thinks "delay line memory" could result on-screen alphanumerics.  The best I can come up with is the idea that the output of the memory is used to control the beam brightness, with the cycle time of the memory tightly matched to the refresh rate of the display, so as to produce the right dots at the right time. But I don't find it convincing.  Care to elaborate?

Comment: That system is from early 1970's, I'm looking for radar screens from approx late 1940's,  that could generate  alpha or numeric characters onto the screen ( so not using a transparent physical overlay on the screen as was one method ), which I have noticed at least once on tv, the brief footage appeared to be from approx late 1940's, - The  Manchester Baby / Manchester Mark 1 from that time could output to a CRT screen, maybe letters or numbers if they wanted -

Comment: The charactron displays were a later invention - Raffzahn typed in his reply comment above "those displays were based on special to type vector displays", replying to my comment above mentioning the time period as being approx late 1940's

Comment: So looking for the earliest radar or anything could generate letters or numbers onto the screen, in a useful way like an updated radar image etc, obviously Delay-line memory could do this in the crt-screen-compact-calculators, but looking for the earliest, obviously interesting, I just noticed charactron was from 1953-54, but am not sure it was used in radar, and maybe not the earliest method due Manchester Baby / Manchester Mark 1 machines

Comment: Not sure why you keep saying "delay-line." For a _general purpose_ computer or calculator, the choice of technology for the main memory (delay line, Williams tube, core, IDK-what-else) would have been a tradeoff between cost and speed and size, but it would _not_ have made any difference to what kind of operations the computer could do on the data. OTOH, it might be a different story if you were talking about some highly-specialized computing machine such as a signal processing component in a radar set, but any alphanumeric data shown on a screen would not have come from the DSP.

Comment: I don't believe the Baby or Mark 1 had on-screen alphanumerics; state of the art was reading the dots (individual bits) on the Williams tube storage -- i.e., peering at the actual memory. Actual I/O was via teleprinter with 5-channel paper tape.

Answer (score 10):

In computing's early history, the main limit was not usually speed, but memory capacity.  This is sometimes still true today.

Many of those 1960s calculators are indeed basically little microcontrollers, with a sequencer as sophisticated as a general purpose CPU.  With the right design, A  bit-serial processor in that style, would be fine for word processing.  It'd be fast enough, and relatively cheap and compact -- it could probably fit on a single large PCB even with 1960s discrete technology.

As foreshadowed, the problem is the memory.  A classic computer-style word processor is going to be at least several kilobytes of software.  Probably many tens of kilobytes.  Documents will need at least a few kilobytes of memory for buffers while edited.  And so on.

We might try to avoid even that!  No software, per se.  Just a simple sequencer, and a buffer, tied to an IO device and a CRT tube.  Read or type bytes in to point at buffer, read bytes out to tape or printer.

We still need the buffer.  Perhaps 40x12 8-bit characters.  Small screen but usable.  480 bytes.  Plus assorted state and etc.  Many hundreds more bytes.

> A reason for asking is to possibly discover unknown machines.

You might be interested in the [IBM MT/ST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_MT/ST), released in 1964.  It was a Selectric typewriter with a magnetic tape unit.  It worked somewhat like a Flexowriter, which was a similar typewriter system but which ran off paper tape.  They could be used to edit documents, in a way.

It would have been technically possible to do a similar thing with a CRT display in the 1960s.  The first use of a minicomputer with a CRT display to edit documents dates to at least around 1960.  But CRT text displays required what was then a very large amount of memory, and high speed electronics.

Those desk calculators typically had both RAM and ROM measured in bits, not even kilobits.  They'd need 10x as much memory or more.  Even with delay line memory being the cheapest kind of memory, this is starting to get very expensive.  Such a machine would cost roughly around as much as a car did at the time.  With specialization it'd be cheaper than a full-blown minicomputer, but not a typical office device.  Mainly for cost reasons it did not become common technology until the 1970s.  Integrated circuits really did change everything.

> video games

Pong came out in 1972. Nothing really prevented someone from designing something similar in the 1960s, with a more complex sequencer and more state, although it would have been accordingly more expensive to manufacture and so I doubt there would have been a market.

Comment: Pong was a latecomer to the computer-gaming scene.  [OXO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OXO_(video_game)) pre-dated it by twenty years.

Answer (score 5):

TL;DR: No and Rather Not.

> CRT-Screen-Compact-Desktop-Calculators of the 60's

Assuming this is about the [Friden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friden,_Inc.) EC130/132/1162 series, using a CRT for stack display and a [magneto resistive delay line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delay-line_memory#Magnetostrictive_delay_lines) as working storage, like shown here:

[image]

Then the answer is a clear:

- Word Processor: **NO**
- Games: **Rather NOT**

This is simply due the fact that the delay line memory misses even the tiniest amount of storage to do anything useful. The 5ms line used in the Friden EC130 series (*1), was barely enough to hold 5 registers with 13 decimal places or 65 decimal numbers at whole. Each digit was stored as zero to nine pulses.

---

> Word-Processors - How difficult would it have been to save what was on the delay-line memory onto tape.

Not so much. Still might have cost a few hundred to a thousand 1960 USD (*2) to operate such a tape reliable. But even beside that, it would have taken way more than the available 65 decimal digits of storage to do some useful editing - not to mention that an according display would as well have needed way more storage than the procedural generated decimal digits.

> (A simple cable could have connected to printers, or simply take tapes to compatible printers )

A 'simple cable' do what to a 'what'? Sorry, but that part wasn't invented back then. Printers were special to design. Sure, in the early 1960s CDC (and later others) started to build peripherals compatible with (mostly) IBM mainframes, but this as the upper end of market, not anything to come near a calculator type device - in fact, even the interface to handle them might have needed more electronics than the whole Friden 130.

Companies like Centronics, offering vendor independent devices, only came up in the mid 1970s. And no, TTY were not generic.

> Video-Games - This would probably involve more circuitry / logic, and of course very few could have afforded one for video games.

Unless this is about some number games, it would have needed a complete different machine. Sure, such could have been designed, but it would not resemble any calculator - after all, why should it.

> NOTE - I cannot find how data on Delay-line memory was edited after input, assuming some machines allowed editing, these crt-calculators would probably not have.

It's a [RPN stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation). A new number could be entered to replace the top entry (bottom line) as often as needed, or the whole stack could be cleared. So, yes, editing was there.

Keep in mind, these were calculators, not computers, and reduced to the minimum needed. Real computers would use drum memory (like the [prototype(s) for the EC130](https://www.oldcalculatormuseum.com/friden130.html) did), or, for extreme high speed, core memory.

Core is what HP used in 1968 for their HP9100, which in turn wasn't a calculator, but already a programmable computer (*3) with 'much' more memory - still not really enough to do serious word processing, not even for a tweet.

Then again, this is already the time when short after full desktop systems like the Datapoint 2200 or [Cogar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Cogar) 4 became available, using solid state memory and a CRT.

---

Long story short, any word processor would (and have) used different technology than the Friden calculators. Likewise any game. It could have been done, but wouldn't have been related.

---

*1 - The EC132 only differs AFAIR by the way an empty register is filled if values are popped, by copying the TOS value - creating an implied constant memory. The EC1162 again is a cost and size reduced version using integrated circuits.

*2 - The Olivetti [MLU 600](https://www.1000bit.it/ad/bro/olivetti/mlu600/ln600_bro.asp) tape, used with the 1971 [P602](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olivetti_P602) calculator/computer cost ca. 700 USD. So a mid 1960s unit migh have been easy past 1000 USD. Quite a lot considering that a new VW Beatle was USD 1500 in 1960 :))

*3 - Which in turn meant that a court forced them to pay the enormous sum of 900,000 USD to Olivetti for infringing their patents on the [Programma 101](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programma_101) series of 1965 - which in fact used delay line memory (with a size of ca. 240 of today's bytes), but had only a printer for output.

Answer (score -1):

People could and did use Teletype machines for word processing: type the text to paper tape, then run sections of the tape through a reader with output through a punch to edit (if you had that capability) or cut and paste the tape to edit.

And that overlapped with one-line calculators, so you could have used an LCD display to show what your were reading and punching. But in practice, the people editing paper tape could normally read characters directly from the hole pattern -- they didn't need a typewriter or lcd display to see what they were doing.

Comment: LCD displays weren't even invented until 1968, and it was several years before they were used for calculators, let alone alphanumeric displays. Calculator displays at the time were CRTs (as in the question here) or nixie tubes or similar.